# Custom iterator for multiple containers in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I have a pure abstract class and two derived classes that I use to store the same kind of data, let's say `int`, but in different data structures, let's say a `map` and a `vector`.

```
class AbstractContainer {
  public:
    virtual MyIterator firstValue() = 0;
}

class ContainerMap : public AbstractContainer {
  private:
    map<K, int>;
  public:
    MyIterator firstValue() { // return iterator over map values (int) }
}

class ContainerVector : public AbstractContainer {
  private:
    vector<int>;
  public:
    MyIterator firstValue() { // return iterator over vector values (int) }
}
```

In `ContainerMap`  I can subclass `map<K, int>::iterator` to iterate over the map values.

But how can I define a generic iterator `MyIterator`, independent of the data structure, in such a way that given a pointer of type `AbstractContainer` I can iterate over the values ignoring the actual structure storing the data? And besides that, is this a good practice?

**Edit**

This question is a simplification of the problem. In my project one of the subclasses store my objects in memory (in a `std::map`) while the other retrieves the objects from an external database. I am trying to create a common interface to access the collection of objects, that is independent of the data source because the operations (search, insertion and deletion) would be exactly the same.

Comment: Look at how it is done in std, with common typedefs defining the iterator within the template. Of course I assumed you were doing it for fun. This is HORRIBLE practice. Use the std for any real code.

Comment: Type Erasure for iterators is good reference to start. [http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/start_page.html](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/start_page.html)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the reason why you claim this is an horrible practice. I am using std for the data structures whenever possible... I just want the way I access the objects to be the same for different data structures

Answer (score 1):

Well, no, it's not good practice.

The reason that there is more than one container type (for example, in the STL) is that there is no single container that is optimised for everything.   So, one container type might be better suited to a use case where elements are inserted into a container once and it is iterated over multiple times, and another container might be better suited to code that needs to repeatedly add and remove elements from the middle.

The reason STL containers each specify their own iterators is that iterating over each container works in different ways.   An iterator suited to working with a vector will - at best - be inefficient on a list and - at worst - will not work correctly.

That said, as in the STL, there is nothing stopping two different containers using the same name for their iterators.   So `Container_X` and `Container_y` can both have an iterator named `Iterator`, but `Container_X::Iterator` does not need to work the same way as `Container_Y::Iterator`.

You're not the first person who wants code that is container agnostic (although you've worded it effectively as "agnostic to the iterator").  And you won't be the last.    Unless some great mind manages to specify a container type with all operations optimal for all possible use cases (in contrast with the current state of play which is that each container type is optimal for some use cases but poor for others) container agnostic code is a futile goal.   An iterator that can work across all containers will probably be maximally inefficient, for numerous measures, for one or more operations on most, if not all, of the different container types.

Comment: But my custom iterator would still use `vector::iterator` and `map::iterator` under the hood, each optimized for its data structure... So I don't see why this would be less efficient. The way I think this should work is that, for example, a call to `operator++` of my generic iterator would call `operator++` on the specialized iterator for the container that is being used

Comment: Only if `MyIterator` and therefore `AbstractContainer` is implemented with built-in knowledge of all the specialised containers and their iterators.    Every time you derive a new class from `AbstractContainer`, you will need to modify `MyIterator` so it can work with the iterator for the new container type - while not breaking how it works with other iterators.  That breaks the open-closed principle (i.e. that well designed code is extendable without a need to modify it) and that principle is one of the underpinnings of maintainable and reusable designs or code.

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to do is create a separate iterator class that inherits from the C++ standard iterator class. Then, you would need to implement all the standard iterator functions within your iterator class (i.e dereference, ++, ==, !=, etc.).

Within your data structures you would want to have a function that will return the successor node/value from any point within the structure - this function will be called by the iterator's overloaded ++ operator in order to move to the next node/value in the data structure, in the order you want. For example, for a vector, given an index, you'd want your successor method to return the index that follows the given index in the vector.

From what I understand, though, you want your iterator to be generic so that you could use the same iterator class for more than one data structure. This might be possible through the use of templates and checks within your iterator class; however, it will probably not be a very secure implementation - not recommended.

Is it bad practice to subclass a standard library data structure and do what you're trying to do here? In the real world it would probably be considered bad practice, yes. But for experimentation purposes or a personal project, I'm sure it would be a good learning experience!

Comment: I don't want to implement an iterator from scratch since this is very dangerous. And I don't think this is what I need because I could still use stl iterators under the hood. `ContainerMap` would use `map::iterator` while `ContainerVector` would use `vector::iterator`. But since there is no common base class for these two iterators I don't have a type to declare in `AbstractClass`